# Portainer - Docker Swarm - Send request to all nodes (Instances)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-swarm, spring-rabbit, portainer

I am building an Application which Listens to multiple Rabbit MQ QUEUES and does the logic and creates a file to FTP, I have controlled the listener for each queue using "RabbitListenerContainerFactory".

Based upon the FTP location availability I will control the Listener to Listen for the Message or to be idle.

For Example -
We have two queues

1. queue-a
2. queue-b

Queue-a messages will be picked by

```java
 @Component
public class ListenerForQueueA {

    @RabbitListener
    (queues = "queue-a",
        id = "queue-a", containerFactory = "myRabbitListenerContainerFactory")
    public void processOrder(String message) throws Exception {
        //businesslogic
    
    }
```

Queue-b messages will be picked by

```java
 @Component
public class ListenerForQueueB {

    @RabbitListener
    (queues = "queue-b",
        id = "queue-b", containerFactory = "myRabbitListenerContainerFactory")
    public void processOrder(String message) throws Exception {
        //businesslogic
    
    }
```

My Rabbit Config -

```java
 @Bean
  public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory myRabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
      SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
      factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
      factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);
      factory.setBatchListener(true);
      return factory;
  }
```

Controller -

```java
    @PostMapping("/startListener")
    ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> startListener(@RequestParam String queueName) {
        start(queueName);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    
    @PostMapping("/stopListener")
    ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> getRegisters(@RequestParam String queueName) {
        stop(queueName);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    
    public void start(String queueName) {
        MessageListenerContainer containers =  registry.getListenerContainer(queueName);
        if(!containers.isRunning()){
            logger.info(queueName+" is resuming its listening");
            containers.start();
        }
    }
    
    public void stop(String queueName) {
        
        MessageListenerContainer containers =  registry.getListenerContainer(queueName);
        if(containers.isRunning()) {
            logger.info(queueName+ " is running and It's about to be stoped");
            containers.stop();
        }
            }
```

Now When I deploy this application in Portainer services with single instance, It works as expected.  But when I increase the scalability from 1 to 3 instances and when I try to stop the listener, It stops in  one of the instance only but still the queue message is been picked. :(

please help me on resolving this. One Stop API call to stop all Listeners to stop listening the messaging queue.

I am new to docker and portainer.

Comment: I am not familiar with portainer but you need to call `/stopListener` on each instance.

Comment: Thats the problem. We may have multiple instance on the same box itself if we scale up the Instance in portainer service.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the instances are on the same box or not; you still need to make the call to each instance.